# Correct syntax for file path in background-image:url(''); in a twig file (building template for mautic)

Tags: css, symfony, twig, background-image, filepath

<sub>I started to work with mautic (open source email marketing automation).
Im trying to build a template for a landing page and therefore I'm editing "*.html.twig" files. At least I could find out that twig is a PHP engine by Symfony. What I could not find out yet though is something actually totally simple, at least in css/html.</sub>

**All I want to do is specify the correct file path to an image file as a background-image:url(''); within the style attribute of the body tag.** (See example below)

How on earth is this twig working with file paths? It seems to automatically change the file path I specify, but in a way that is not comprehensible to me.

I tried several options, but the only thing that works at least partially is specifying the absolute path. As soon as I start using the template in mautic though and build a page from it and save it, even the absolute file-path gets 'crashed' on the output source code. What the heck?

I did not find much info on file path syntax in twig. What I found sounded so horribly complicated that I can't believe it should really be that complicated to simply put in a file path? Am I wrong?

**Here is the example, specifying the absolute path in the actual source code.**

```
<body style="background-image:url('http://sawiya.de/mautic/themes/mautictheme1/img/background.jpg'); background-color:#213E4C;">
```

**When viewing the result in the browser**, without adding content to the landing page template, the source code output is the following (path changed, but the result is at least that the image is being shown):

```
background-image:url(http://1.1.1.2/bmi/1.1.1.5/bmi/sawiya.de/mautic/themes/mautictheme1/img/background.jpg);
```

**After adding content on top of the template in mautic**, the file path is being changed even more and reads the following from the source code output (now the background image does not get displayed anymore, so its clearly broken):

```
background-image: url(http://1.1.1.3/bmi/sawiya.de/mautic/"http://1.1.1.5/bmi/sawiya.de/mautic/themes/mautictheme1/img/background.jpg")
```

What is this all about? Where can I get the info on how to easily and correctly specify the file path? Is it really that hard?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found out something strange. It might be a bug in mautic here.

When I open the page where I specified the image via the background-image:url() through the http**s**:// -Protocol, instead of http://, **it works!**

And the resulting source code looks as expected:

```
background-image: url(&quot;http://1.1.1.5/bmi/sawiya.de/mautic/themes/mautictheme1/img/background.jpg&quot;)
```

So, wrong adress here, I think. At least to solve the bug. Hope someone finds this as a solution, until the bug is fixed.

Cheers!

**Edit:** Of course its better to specify the **file path** in a **relative** way, so that when the theme is used on another server, the path is still correct. In twig the best way to do that seems to be this. At least it works perfectly well.

```
background-image: url('{{ getAssetUrl('themes/'~template~'/img/logo.png', null, null, true) }}';)
```